# How to change format number in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, number-formatting

I have the following views count function for wordpress post. However, the number that comes up is for example 2000, while I'm trying to get 2.000.

Located in Functions.php

```
add_action ('elementor/query/popular_post', function ($query) {
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    $query->set('meta_key', 'views');
});
```

Located in Header.php

```
<?php
if (is_singular('post')) {
    $count = get_field('views');
    $count ++;
    update_field('views', $count);
}
?>
```

I tried googling and changed the code several times but couldn't change the format of the numbers. Would anyone be kind enough to give a Tips?

I'm sorry for not being able to replicate the function in JsFiddle or similar, but I believe this is not possible.

I don't know php, I'm a fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use number_format() function here:
[www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp)

See last example here where they set for as thousands separator:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_string_number_format

Your code updated as below I believe:

```
update_field('views', number_format($count,0,",","."));
```

Comment: I've already tried with the PHP and W3 references, but I don't know where to apply those bits of code for the format number.

Comment: I have updated my answer with change added to code

Comment: Before posting the question I had consulted the references and tried to "play" with the code. However, I had no idea where to place the code part for the format number. Anyway I really appreciate the help of stack users, I always learn new things.

Comment: Writing the formatted number into the field, does not sound like a good idea. You'd be storing `2.000` here, that _can_ only be a string value. So when this gets read back, the attempt to increase that value with `++`, will require casting `2.000` into a number first, the result of that will be `2`, and thereby `++` will result in `3`. This kind of formatting should only be applied where the value gets _output_, not where it gets _stored_.

Answer (score 1):

See the reference on [PHP: number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: I see you do not yet have **50 reps**, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Alternatively, add this function to the OP's code and post as part of  your answer

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad expression on the question, but having nothing knowledge I don't know how to orient the question. I just took the code that gives the number of views and posted here on the stack thinking it was just a question of PHP. 

Forgive my ignorance, what do you mean by Op's code?

Comment: OP = Original poster (you, the person posted the question)